# Dynamic Table Columns Issue

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There is no issue with the data being passed to Flask via the Jscript, that seems to be fine. But actually using the columns with 'spAdvertisedProduct.query.with_entities' doesn't seem to work.

My goal is to change the column names/values dynamically using checkboxes. The tables in Flask are already showing dynamic headers/rows using JINJA. This would just be a nice to have on top of that.

My code:
Python -

```
@main.route('/update-columns', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def data():
    # Retrieve the list of selected columns from the submitted form
    res = request.json
    table_data = res['columns']
    #pre_res = ["spAdvertisedProduct." + sub for sub in table_data]
    selected_columns = [text(col) for col in table_data]
    print(selected_columns)
    data = spAdvertisedProduct.query.with_entities(*selected_columns).all()

    # Retrieve the data from the database, selecting only the desired columns
    # Render the table in the template, using only the selected columns
    return render_template('adsdash.html', column_names=table_data, data=data)
```

JScript -

```
var confirmButton = document.getElementById('confirmColumns');
confirmButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked[id^="columncheck_"]');
    var selectedColumns = Array.from(checkboxes, function(checkbox) {
    var label = checkbox.closest('label');
    if (label !== null) {
        return label.textContent.trim();
    }
    return null;
}).filter(function(textContent) {
    return textContent !== null;
});


fetch('/update-columns', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({ columns: selectedColumns }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})

.then(function(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
  }
  return response.text();
})
.then(function(responseText) {
  console.log(responseText);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
});
});
```

When attempting to change the columns selected in Flask using sqlAlchemy, I receive the following:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1109, "Unknown table 'spAdvertisedProduct' in field list")
```

I have attempted removing 'spAdvertisedProduct.' as a prefix, which returned the following:

`(1054, "Unknown column 'campaignId' in 'field list'")`

Comment: Can you try and replace `data = spAdvertisedProduct.query.with_entities(*selected_columns).all()` with `data = spAdvertisedProduct.query.with_entities(*[getattr(spAdvertisedProduct, column) for column in selected_columns]).all()`?

Comment: Perfect! 

I also had to change 'selected_columns = [text(col) for col in table_data]' to: selected_columns = [str(col) for col in table_data]

Then using JScript I did the following:
.then(response => response.text())
.then(html => {
        // Update the table with the new HTML
        $('#table-data').html(html);
})'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the line :

```py
data = spAdvertisedProduct.query.with_entities(*selected_columns).all()
```

to

```py
table_data = spAdvertisedProduct.query.with_entities(*[getattr(spAdvertisedProduct, column) for column in selected_columns]).all()
```

resolves the issue.